# PATH Environment variable failed during Oracle Database 12c installation

Tags: oracle, environment-variables

I facing an error when i try to install the latest Oracle Database 12c. It's happen at the stage of **Prerequisite Checks** in which it stated that Environment variable named PATH failed. Anyone know how to solve this issue ? I don't even know what is Environment variable. :P

What is the **value** should be for **PATH variable** used for Oracle Database 12c ?

Comment: Sounds like your path environment variable is too big. You could execute the dos command, `echo %PATH% > path.txt`.  Open the file and tell us how many characters long it is. This problem has occurred with other people (e.g. https://community.oracle.com/thread/2324979?start=0&tstart=0).

Comment: Useless.  It has nothing to do with the Path Environment variable as i already try to shorten it but the same failed occur. I even try to rename from Path to PATH also failed. Is that because i had MS SQL installed so it prevent me to install Oracle Database 12c ?

Comment: Not clear what operating system you are using,  There is this known bug here, `Oracle Database/Client Installation 12.1.0.2/12.2.0.1 raises PRVF-3919 ON WINDOWS 10 Build 1703 (Doc ID 2307844.1)`

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 Pro